# Document should be editable but not be able to be saved

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a word document in 2010. The document is a series of questions to be asked to the customer. All the technicians open the document while talking to the customer. Technicians should be able to write in the document but if they try to save it, it should prevent them from doing so. How is this possible.
In word 2007, I kept a password for the document. so it gives an options to do ready only if you don't know the password.

Comment: The option you used within `Word 2007` still exists with `Word 2010`

Comment: Make the file read-only.

Comment: You can probably get this behavior by converting the document to PDF.

Answer (score 4):

Use a Word *template* ([DOTX](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/word-help/save-a-word-document-as-a-template-HA010030754.aspx)) instead of a *document* (DOCX), as your master/source.

> A template is a document type that creates a copy of itself when you open it.

This will allow them to edit it and even save it (if desired), but won't save over the original source document (template).

> All you have to do is open a template and fill in the text and the information that is specific to your document. *When you save the document as a .docx or .docm file, you save your document separately from the template on which it is based*.

Lots of info and instruction on templates is available in Word's help, and at office.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 1):

Click *file > save as*, choose a template file [image]

Save this in each users' template folder, and it will be selectable as a template when they open up Word.

Alternatively, save the document anywhere, right click and go to properties and choose "*read only*". This will allow them to open the document but will be presented with the "*Save as*" box when they go to save it.